How to extract the active dag from airflow which running on aws as mwaa using python
I have export the access key and secret key from my local system and I am able to do aws s3 ls
How to extract all the active dag below is the script

import boto3

# Create an MWAA client
mwaa_client = boto3.client('mwaa')

# Specify your MWAA environment name
environment_name = 'test-mwaa-airflow'

# Get the MWAA environment details
response = mwaa_client.get_environment(Name=environment_name)
print('response', response)

# find the active tags

getting eror botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the GetEnvironment operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
aws mwaa get-environment --name test-mwaa-airflow
giving me the all the details of the environment
